# Hosting Panel Pterodactyl can't reach it's daemon, connections to port 8080 timeout

Tags: linux, networking, google-cloud-platform, virtualhost, daemon

I am almost done installing the [Pterodactyl Panel](https://pterodactyl.io) on my Google Cloud VM instance. In a nutshell, this software can be installed on Linux and acts as a panel to manage and host servers. These servers include but are not limited to Minecraft, Discord Bots, Rust, Teamspeak, Voiceservers, Twitch Bots, etc.

There are basically to parts to parts to install: the panel, and the daemon. Essentially from my understanding, the daemons the server instances, node, and some other stuff. The panel acts as the interface that you configure your server with and is the whole webserver itself (NGNIX, or APACHE, I am using NGNIX). You can also choose to run it with SSL or without.
If you don't know about or haven't setup Pterodactyl before you may not be able to understand what you could do to help haha.

When I run my panel/webserver on port 80 I get a connection, hence me using the panel to come across this problem. Since I am using google cloud there are firewall rules, but [one rule allows ingress traffic through all ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkYNe.jpg). The daemon uses port 8080, but when I address it in the CLI using `curl ip.ip.ip:8080` or ping it, I'll get no connection which times out. As a result of this, the status under my nodes section on the panel is a [red heart, not a green one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkse3.jpg).

In the Pterodactyl discord server, their support bot [had this to say about the daemon log I uploaded in chat.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ4zQ.jpg) The command I did that the bot said shown in the second image; `netstat -tulpn`. [Here is the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSbAL.jpg) As you can see, there is port 0.0.0.0:8080 listed there. Of course, it would be because when I started the daemon with `systemctl` it showed that the daemon *was* listening on 0.0.0.0:8080. So the daemon is listening on the right port and such, and I know it is active when I did `systemctl status wings`. So if that is all running and my firewall rules on google cloud all trffic through ports, why can't I ping port 8080 on my IP? I thought that I needed to have a firewall set up on my VM itself, and I tried `ufw`, but I had no luck. I didn't restart my machine or anything for the `ufw` rules to take effect, because I believe they already do without any help. For the picture of that red heart, a showed you earlier, there was a tooltip to say to check my browser console for errors, just wanted to mention that the console nothing. The Linux version is Debian 10 btw.

I believe that is all I have to say about this. No one has helped figure this out so far on the discord server. They're a bit edgy too...  If anyone can help that would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Can you provide some insight to the following questions: 1) Where are they trying to ping the IP and port? VM instance? Cloud shell? Or a third party tool on their laptop?
2) Can you proivde some context on the statement "No luck when they tried ufw"? Does this mean that it shows nothing or the FW is enabled/disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Port 8080 is a pretty standard alt port for http. **Try changing the port to something else** (that you're not using) and try again.

I ran into this problem running Pterodactyl on my local network and forwarding required ports. It turned out my router was internally set up to listen for ISP management connections on port 8080 and was intercepting and timing out the requests.

Also, if you are using `ufw` or any other firewall, make sure you're forwarding both ports (daemon and SFTP) you set up for `wings`. And if you're specifying a FQDN, make sure your DNS records are in order and your SSL certificates are where Pterodactyl is expecting them.